# По заданию нужно циклично сдвинуть строки прямоугольной матрицы на К элементов вправо

Tags: java

На выходе матрица сдвигается влево. И я лишь могу предположить, что сдвигаю в несколько кругов, но как исправить? Я совсем новичок в этом, помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i, j, m = 5, n = 6;
        int[][] mass = new int[m][n]; 
        System.out.println("Исходная матрица:");
        for(i = 0; i < m; i++){
            for(j = 0 ; j < n ; j++){
                mass[i][j] = (int)(n*(Math.random()*15-5));
                System.out.printf("%3d\t", mass[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.print("Введите число для сдвига: ");
        int num = in.nextInt();
        if (num < 0){System.out.print("Сдвиг невозможен. "); System.exit(0);}
        if (num == 0 || num == 6){
            for(i = 0; i < m; i++){
                for(j = 0 ; j < n ; j++)
                    System.out.printf("%3d\t", mass[i][j]);
            System.out.println();
            }
        }
        else{
            if (num > n) num = num%n;
            for(i = 0; i < m; i++){
                int l = 0; 
                for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
                    if (j+num >= n){
                        l = Math.abs(n-(j+num));
                        System.out.printf("%3d\t", mass[i][l]);
                    }
                    else System.out.printf("%3d\t", mass[i][j+num]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: вот что получается]

Comment: В данной реализации содержимое матрицы не меняется, сдвиг выполняется только _при выводе_, так и задумывалось?

Comment: @NowhereMan так и задумывалось, да

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо всей этой катавасии после `if (num < 0)...` оставьте вот что:

```
int mult = num / n + 1;
for(i = 0; i < m; i++){
     for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
          System.out.printf("%3d\t", mass[i][(j-num + mult*n)%n]);
     }
     System.out.println();
}
```

Для сдвига **вправо** - на j-м месте должен быть выведен элемент, который находился на num позиций **левее**. С учётом цикличности и обеспечением положительности значения это будет индекс `(j-num + mult*n)%n`

Comment: Так ли необходим коэффициент `mult`?  Для `num < n` он выродится в 1 и значение индекса со сдвигом будет вычислено как `j-num + n`; для `num` кратных `n` после вычисления остатка индекс останется неизменным `j`; для `num > n` значение `num` будет приведено к диапазону `[0..n - 1]`; для отрицательных значений (сдвига влево) `j - num + mult * n` будет положительным числом.

Comment: @Nowhere Man Да, он именно для последнего случая, чтобы выражение под модулем было положительно, т.к. % в Java в этом случае, как я прочитал, даёт отрицательный остаток [int e = (-5)%3;  // -2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3) (в разных языках по-разному)

Answer (score 0):

В представленном коде при *увеличении* индекса `j + num` происходит сдвиг *влево*, для данных значений `num = 13 % 6 = 1` в каждой строке сначала выводится элемент строки с индексом 1, затем с индексом 2, и в конце с индексом 0 (`n - (j + 1)` при `j = n - 1` даёт 0).

Соответственно, для сдвига *вправо* надо изменить знак при расчёте индекса, чтобы сначала выводился последний элемент строки с индексом `n - 1`, затем с нулевым индексом, затем индексом 1 и т.д.:

```java
static void printShiftedRight(int[][] arr, int shift) {
    shift = shift % arr[0].length;
    
    for (int[] row : arr) {
        for (int j = 0, n = row.length; j < n; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%3d\t", row[(n + j - shift) % n]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Соответственно, для сдвига *влево* нужна формула `(n + j + shift) % n`:

```java
static void printShiftedLeft(int[][] arr, int shift) {
    shift = shift % arr[0].length;
    
    for (int[] row : arr) {
        for (int j = 0, n = row.length; j < n; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%3d\t", row[(n + j + shift) % n]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Тест:

```java
System.out.println("Исходная матрица: ");
printShiftedRight(arr, 0);

System.out.println("----");
System.out.println("Матрица со сдвигом вправо");
printShiftedRight(arr, 13);

System.out.println("----");
System.out.println("Матрица с отрицательным сдвигом вправо");
printShiftedRight(arr, -1);

System.out.println("----");
System.out.println("Матрица со сдвигом влево ");
printShiftedLeft(arr, 1);
```

Результат:

```
Исходная матрица: 
 -1 -27 -23  24  41  47 
 57  15  44  32  47  29 
 18 -24 -20  -3  -8  22 
----
Матрица со сдвигом вправо
 47  -1 -27 -23  24  41 
 29  57  15  44  32  47 
 22  18 -24 -20  -3  -8 
----
Матрица с отрицательным сдвигом вправо
-27 -23  24  41  47  -1 
 15  44  32  47  29  57 
-24 -20  -3  -8  22  18 
----
Матрица со сдвигом влево 
-27 -23  24  41  47  -1 
 15  44  32  47  29  57 
-24 -20  -3  -8  22  18
```